# Is it possible to add application specific key-bindings?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, ubuntu-14.04

Is it possible to create keyboard shortcut to run an application specific function? I know how to create system wide keyboard shortcuts through `Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts`, but I don't see a way to make the key-bindings specific to an application.

So as an example, if I wanted to create a keyboard shortcut to open a new tab in gnome-terminal. I would want a shortcut to run `File > Open Tab > 0. Default`.

Another example would if I wanted to change an existing application keyboard shortcut. Perhaps I want gnome-terminal's `shift+ctrl+w` to be `shift+ctrl+x`.

*note: There is already a keyboard shortcut to create a new tab in terminal, but my question still stands. The terminal example is just that, an example.*

Answer (score 0):

After shirtcuts go to Custom shortcuts and click the + sign button and you get a menu fill the name and the command to open the application. Like to open the terminal use "gnome-terminal" then click on the add button after saving that click on disabled keyword to add the custom key for that shortcut.

Comment: Wouldn't that just be a shortcut to open terminal? I already know how to create a shortcut to open an application, I'm talking about a shortcut to run an application specific function.

Comment: I edited my question to make it more clear.